# Property or method "greet" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Same time I got an another error, which is "Invalid handler for event "click"".

```
<template>
    
    <div id="example-2">
      <!-- `greet` is the name of a method defined below -->
      <button v-on:click="greet">Greet</button>
    </div>
    
    </template>
    
    <script>
    window.onload = function () {
    
    var example2 = new Vue({
      el: '#example-2',
      data: {
        name: 'Vue.js'
      },
      // creating method greet
      methods: {
        greet: function (event) {
          // `this` inside methods points to the Vue instance
          alert('Hello ' + this.name + '!')
          // `event` is the native DOM event
          if (event) {
            alert(event.target.tagName)
          }
        }
      }
    })
    
    }
    
    </script>
```

Comment: never seen anyone put the script contents in a .vue file inside `window.onload = function () {` ... try not doing that

Comment: What sort of file is this? You can't really use the `<template>` tag unless you're writing a single-file Vue component. If it is a single-file-component, you wouldn't typically create a new `Vue` instance within it. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html

Comment: @JaromandaX if I remove "window.onload = function ()", i get this error. "Cannot find element: #example-2"

Comment: @Phil So can you please guide me to execute this new vue instance without <template>?

Comment: read https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/

Comment: @Ramzan Are you trying to do it in simple `html` file using cdn ? I did it quite a few times, if that's the case maybe I could help

Answer (score 1):

the `template` tag is hidden when the HTML loads so you get the error `cannot find element` or something like that. You can load it with javascript.

Vue.js does not use the built in `template` tag.

However if you using it over cdn try it like this

```
  <div id="example-2">
    <button v-on:click="greet">Greet</button>
  </div>

  <script>
    var example2 = new Vue({
      el: "#example-2",
      data: {
        name: "Vue.js",
      },
      methods: {
        greet: function(event) {
          alert("Hello " + this.name + "!");
          if (event) {
            alert(event.target.tagName);
          }
        },
      },
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can simply do is remove the `template` tags

Here is the working code:
https://jsfiddle.net/t49zxdov/2/

```
<div id="example-2">
      <!-- `greet` is the name of a method defined below -->
      <button v-on:click="greet">Greet</button>
    </div>
```

```
window.onload = function () {
    
        var example2 = new Vue({
      el: '#example-2',
      data: {
        name: 'Vue.js'
      },
      // creating method greet
      methods: {
        greet: function (event) {
          // `this` inside methods points to the Vue instance
          alert('Hello ' + this.name + '!')
          // `event` is the native DOM event
          if (event) {
            alert(event.target.tagName)
          }
        }
      }
    })
    
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should separate your vue template and the vue instance. To do that,

create file, ex: `example.vue`
copy this code

```
<template>
    <div id="example-2">
      <!-- `greet` is the name of a method defined below -->
      <button v-on:click="greet">Greet</button>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
  data() {
     return {
         name: 'Vue.js'
     }
  },
  methods: {
        greet: function (event) {
          // `this` inside methods points to the Vue instance
          alert('Hello ' + this.name + '!')
          // `event` is the native DOM event
          if (event) {
            alert(event.target.tagName)
          }
        }
      }
</script>
```

and create this file, ex: `app.js`

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#example-2', 
});
```

and then link your `app.js` to your index layout.

I hope you get my point. thanks